# Why does interpolation search calculate the position same as linear search

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am going through a data structures and algorithms book and in the section about interpolation search of arrays, the book includes this piece of code:

```py
def interpolation_search(ar:list, lo:int, hi:int, x:int):                                
    if (lo <= hi and x >= ar[lo] and x <= ar[hi]):                                       
        pos = lo + ((hi - lo) // (ar[hi] - ar[lo]) * (x - ar[lo]))                       
                                                                                           
        print(pos)                                                                       
                                                                                             
        if ar[pos] == x:                                                                 
            return pos                                                                   
                                                                                           
        if ar[pos] < x:                                                                  
            return interpolation_search(ar, pos + 1, hi, x)                              
                                                                                             
        if ar[pos] > x:                                                                  
            return interpolation_search(ar, lo, pos - 1, x)                              
                                                                                             
    return -1 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                               
    v = 18                                                                                                                                                 
    ar = [10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 33, 35, 42, 47]                                                           
    assert(interpolation_search(ar, 0, len(ar)-1, v) == 4)
```

Now the question I have is, if I run that, it prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (from print(pos))
This seems like a more complicated linear search.

So what am I missing or is this code wrong?

I expect this interpolation search to cut up the array into two based on the logic of the formula, but the it seems the output of the formula is always i, i+1, i+2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calculating `pos` correctly. You're using integer division too early in the expression -- you have to do the multiplication first, then divide. If you do the division first, it gets rounded down before multiplying and you lose precision.

It also caused a division by zero error when searching for the last element in the array.

```
def interpolation_search(ar:list, lo:int, hi:int, x:int):
    if (lo <= hi and x >= ar[lo] and x <= ar[hi]):
        pos = lo + ((hi - lo) * (x - ar[lo])) // (ar[hi] - ar[lo])

        print(pos)

        if ar[pos] == x:
            return pos

        if ar[pos] < x:
            return interpolation_search(ar, pos + 1, hi, x)

        if ar[pos] > x:
            return interpolation_search(ar, lo, pos - 1, x)

    return -1
```